# How to pass DateTime from Angular JS to HTTP GET WEB API

Tags: angularjs, datetime, asp.net-web-api2, http-get

I have Date Field and Time Field in HTML. I want to pass Datetime from Angular JS to WEB API in HTTP GET Request but I am unable to do so.

**HTML**

```
  <label>Appointment Start Date</label>
    <p class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="dd.MM.yyyy" ng-model="empappt.appstart" is-open="popup1.opened" show-button-bar="false" />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
        </span>
    </p>
    <label>Appointment Start Time</label>
    <input type="time" ng-model="empappt.starttime" />
        <label>Appointment End Date</label>    
        <p class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="dd.MM.yyyy" ng-model="empappt.append" is-open="popup2.opened" show-button-bar="false" />
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open2()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
            </span>
        </p>

        <label>Appointment End Time</label>
   <input type="time" ng-model="empappt.endtime" />
```

**Angular JS Controller**

```
var startTime = $filter('date')($scope.empappt.starttime, "HH:mm");
startTime = startTime.split(':');
var apptStartDate = new Date($scope.empappt.appstart);
apptStartDate.setHours(startTime[0]);
apptStartDate.setMinutes(startTime[1]);
apptStartDate = $filter('date')(apptStartDate, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")

var endTime = $filter('date')($scope.empappt.endtime, "HH:mm");
endTime = endTime.split(':');
var apptEndDate = new Date($scope.empappt.append)
apptEndDate.setHours(endTime[0]);
apptEndDate.setMinutes(endTime[1]);
apptEndDate = $filter('date')(apptEndDate, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")

MetadataOrgFactory.getTriIdApiCall('getempappt', apptStartDate, apptEndDate, function (dataSuccess) {
    $scope.employeeData = dataSuccess;
}, function (dataError) {
});
```

**WEB API**

```
 [Authorize]
 [Route("api/getempappt/{apptstart}/{apptend}")]
 [HttpGet]
 public List<EmployeeViewModel> GetEmpAppt(DateTime apptStart, DateTime apptEnd)
 {
     EmployeeBLL getEmployee = new EmployeeBLL();            
     return getEmployee.GetAvailableEmpAppt(apptStart, apptEnd);
 }
```

**WebAPIConfig.cs**

```
 public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {            
            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
            config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);

            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings =
            new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat,
                DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Local,
            };

            //var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
            //config.EnableCors();
        }
    }
```

However I am giving the following bad request error always whenever I pass values

> http://localhost:XXXXX/api/getempappt/2018-02-21%2010:10/2018-02-23%2009:50
>   400 (Bad Request)
>
> Failed to load
>   http://localhost:XXXXX/api/getempappt/2018-02-21%2010:10/2018-02-23%2009:50:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:XXXXX' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 400.

Please help on this

Comment: covert your string to date then send to your api

Comment: Whenever I convert string to DateTime using "new Date()" then I am getting following error :-  "Failed to load http://localhost:XXXXX/api/getempappt/cc8da07f-5174-e711-a1d4-acd1b8ca3600/Tue%20Feb%2027%202018%2010:10:00%20GMT+0530%20(India%20Standard%20Time)/Tue%20Feb%2027%202018%2012:12:00%20GMT+0530%20(India%20Standard%20Time): Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:XXXXX' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404."

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the angularjs issue, the dates are not passed in correct format.
You are picking out the hour and minute from this

```
var startTime = $filter('date')($scope.empappt.starttime, "HH:mm");
```

But if you look at the url you can se that the HH is 2010 and 2009 which is not correct format.

```
2018-02-21%2010:10/2018-02-23%2009:50
```

Then it looks like you are hitting the CORS issue. Make sure to have enabled CORS in your api. 
To do that, install the nuget package

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors
```

Then in the WebApiConfig class add a CORS rule (In this exampel, we will allow all, but that is up to you to decide how to implement it, read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api))

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

Comment: I have added my WEBApiConfig.cs in my original post. I did like you mentioned which is now commented but it is also not working here. Please suggest

Comment: @user1843970 did you also look at the incorrect date format which you are sending to the backend?

Comment: Yes. %20 is coming as default because of space in between Date and Time. How to overcome this?